# Matlab filter simulation error

Tags: matlab

I made a Wiener filter simulation in matlab but it seem that I made a mistake in the code as the result is incorrect. I would be grateful if somebody glanced at the code and pointed out the error.

Here is the code:

```
k = 1:100;
sigma = 0.1;
s1 = randn(1,100);
n1 = randn(1,100) * sigma;
Pnum = [1 0.1];
Pdenum = [1 0.9];
Gnum = [1 0.9];
Gdenum = [1 0.1];
n = filter(Pnum, Pdenum, n1);
s = filter(Gnum, Gdenum, s1);
x = n + s;
rxx = xcorr(x);
rxs = xcorr(x,s);
toeplitz_rxx = toeplitz(rxx);
wopt = inv(toeplitz_rxx) * rxs;

wopt = inv(toeplitz_rxx) * transpose(rxs); 
s_hat = filter(wopt,1,x);
error = x - s_hat; %this is where the wrong result is being calculated
plot(k,error, 'r',k,s_hat, 'b', k, x, 'g');
```

The problem is that the error calculated is exactly a mirror image of the s_hat.
Surely this cant be right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Vote to close: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 5-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: Yes but this is not a Java or C code. If somebody wants to help he can just paste it into the matlab and see themself. I only provided all the info necessary.

Comment: Debugging is something you should be doing yourself.  Stack Overflow is for when you've exhausted the traditional route to fixing a problem (i.e. once you've narrowed it down to a single line of code that isn't behaving as you expect).

Answer (score 0):

No problem.

I have perfectly a *void* idea of what you are trying to do. But if what you are trying to do is to get some signal to noise ratio, and trying to mimic those effects through some linear 1st order systems, you should correct your `P` and `G` polynomials, which are totally wrong, if that is the case. Type `help filter` and see the `A` and `B` definitions.

This is the correct code:

```
k = 1:100;
sigma = 0.1;
s1 = randn(1,100);
n1 = randn(1,100) * sigma;
Pnum = [0 0.1];
Pdenum = [1 -0.9];
Gnum = [0 0.9];
Gdenum = [1 -0.1];
n = filter(Pnum, Pdenum, n1);
s = filter(Gnum, Gdenum, s1);
x = n + s;
rxx = xcorr(x);
rxs = xcorr(x,s);
toeplitz_rxx = toeplitz(rxx);

wopt = inv(toeplitz_rxx) * transpose(rxs); 
s_hat = filter(wopt,1,x);
error = x - s_hat; %this is where the wrong result is being calculated
plot(k,error, 'r',k,s_hat, 'b', k, x, 'g');
```

There are still an ill-conditioning on the toeplitz. I leave it that way, for you still have fun for dealing with. This is easy to solve too.

THe guys are true. StackOverflow is NOT for solve your homework, but for helping you in finding the light.